# Line item properties not showing in some of the order

Tags: shopify

For some of the orders, the line item properties is not showing in the order details. Has anyone ever encounter this issue?

https://www.canadiancontactlenses.com/

Thanks

Comment: Please share a code that you have or is being used to display line item properties and also the exact page the issue is occurring.

Comment: <input type="text" name="properties[L.BC]" value="8.6" readonly>
<input type="text" name="properties[L.DIA]" value="14.2" readonly>
                <select name="properties[L.Boxes]" id="left-box">
                  <option></option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>